Is there a shorter way to use named optional parameters in a class constructor?
I have a class constructor where i am passing one required parameter and several optional arguments with default values.
Is there a way to do this more elegantly? I feel like I am repeating myself with this.variable_name = arg_name.
class Planet {
    constructor(name, {
        mass = 100000
        ,surface_temperature = 0.0
        ,has_water = false
    } = {}) {
        this.name = name;
        this.mass = mass;
        this.surface_temperature = surface_temperature;
        this.has_water = has_water;
    }
}

This works but ideally I want to only write one line of code to add another class attribute with a default value. The constructor argument names and class attribute names are the same.

class Planet {
constructor(name, { mass = 100000, surface_temperature = 0.0, has_water = false } = {}) {
Object.assign(this, { name, mass, surface_temperature, has_water });
}
}
